# Find row that has the largest sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data for tutors. I recorded hours spent tutoring by month in the SESSION table. I need to know who had the most tutoring hours in March, 2006.

TABLE TUTOR

```
tutorID      
1
2
```

TABLE SESSION

```
tutorID     Hours      Month
1           2          March
1           1          March
2           1          March
```

Expected Output:

```
TutorID
1
```

Comment: Sum of what in the row?

Comment: sum the hours of tutor 1 and tutor 2 for the month of march and return the highest value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
select top 1 sum(Hours), tutorID from SESSION where Month like 'March' group by 
tutorID order by sum(Hours) DESC
```

Comment: Why `like 'March'`? Also what if 2 tutors have the same sum?

Comment: Fair enough, a tad excessive. You also do not have to limit your query by writing "top 1" before your variable-statements, to remove the possibility of missing a draw.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html)s.
The 1st will return all the sums for each tutor.
The 2nd will return the maximum of the sums returned by the 1st cte.
Finally your select statement will return only the tutors from the 1st cte that have sum of hours equal to that maximum returned by the 2nd cte.

```
with 
  sumcte as (
    select tutorID, sum(hours) sumhours 
    from session 
    where month = 'March' -- here there should be another condition for the year?
    group by tutorID 
  ),
  maxcte as (
    select max(sumhours) maxhours from sumcte
  )  
select tutorid from sumcte
where sumhours = (select maxhours from maxcte)
```